# How to create a curvy line joining 3 points in pyqgis3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, vector, curved

I am trying to draw a curvy line joining 3 points. I was using https://webgeodatavore.com/create-qgis-curve-from-python-api.html as reference but it is not giving desired output. I used fromTwoPointsAndCenter() but it is not creating any geometry it seems. Let me know if any mistake in code mentioned below.

```
circularRing = QgsCircularString()
self.coords=[-85534.6616900711, -10367.309304396986, -43303.54744088941, 2626.8796953512283, -29497.22162865693, -33513.20846019849]
    circularRing.fromTwoPointsAndCenter(
QgsPoint(self.coords[0], self.coords[1]),
QgsPoint(self.coords[4], self.coords[5]),
QgsPoint(self.coords[2], self.coords[3]))
    geom_from_curve = QgsGeometry(circularRing)
# Create a feature
    fet = QgsFeature()
# Assign the geometry
    fet.setGeometry(geom_from_curve)
    layer=iface.activeLayer()
    prov1 = layer.dataProvider()
    prov1.addFeatures([fet])
```

ERROR - 'No extent could be determined' while zooming to added feature in vector layer.

Answer (score 3):

The `fromTwoPointsAndCenter()` method creates the `QgsCircularString` object. So, you should do something like:

```py
self.coords=[-85534.6616900711, -10367.309304396986, -43303.54744088941, 2626.8796953512283, -29497.22162865693, -33513.20846019849]
circularRing = QgsCircularString.fromTwoPointsAndCenter(
QgsPoint(self.coords[0], self.coords[1]),
QgsPoint(self.coords[4], self.coords[5]),
QgsPoint(self.coords[2], self.coords[3]))
geom_from_curve = QgsGeometry(circularRing)
# Create a feature
fet = QgsFeature()
# Assign the geometry
fet.setGeometry(geom_from_curve)
layer=iface.activeLayer()
prov1 = layer.dataProvider()
prov1.addFeatures([fet])
```

As a quick check, I ran the following code in the Python console:

```py
coords=[-85534.6616900711, -10367.309304396986, -43303.54744088941, 2626.8796953512283, -29497.22162865693, -33513.20846019849]
circularString = QgsCircularString.fromTwoPointsAndCenter(
QgsPoint(coords[0], coords[1]),
QgsPoint(coords[4], coords[5]),
QgsPoint(coords[2], coords[3]))
#print(circularString)
geom_from_curve = QgsGeometry(circularString)
#print(geom_from_curve)
rb = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
rb.setColor(QColor('red'))
rb.setWidth(2.8)
rb.setToGeometry(geom_from_curve)
rb.show()

#rb.reset()
```

And got the following result (obviously the rubber band is shown in the canvas crs of epsg:3857 as I just used OSM as a basemap for convenience):

[image]